# Nested for loop does not iterate correctly

Tags: javascript, for-loop, nested

I have two strings which I split and want to iterate through, and use the value in an `IF` statement. However, when I print the values the output is not correct (it prints the values multiple times).

**Desired output:**
So basically, in the first iteration of loop I would like to have *BMW* and *car1* as the values. Moreover, going into the `IF` statement this would mean that the variable `year` is set to *1999*.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>
var input = "BMW Volvo Saab";
var brand = input.split(" ");
var brandOut = "";
var i;


var input2 = "car1 car2 car3";
var car = input2.split(" ");
var carOut = "";
var j;



for (i = 0; i < brand.length; i++) {
    for (j = 0; j < car.length; j++) {
    brandOut += brand[i];
    carOut += car[j];


//document.write(brandOut);
//document.write(carOut);

if (carOut == 'car1'){
    var year = "1999"

} else if (carOut == 'car2'){
    var year = "2000"

} else {
    var year = "2001";
}


//do something with the current value of year for each iteration of the loop

    }
}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `carOut += car[i]` --> `carOut` probably equals to "car1" only once per iteration. Maybe you'd like to check `car[j]` instead?

Comment: @Devon Sorry, should remove that!

Comment: Do you want  `BMW car1, BMW car2, BMW car3, Volvo car1, Volvo dar2, ...` or `BMW car1, Volvo car2, ...`, or something else entirely? You need to better describe the output you're after. If you just want `BMW car1` then I don't see the purpose of either loop.

Comment: What is the purpose of the if?? Your statement compares an array with a string. Can you add your desired output

Comment: Sure! In my opinion, using objects instead of parallel arrays makes your code neater and more reliable. So instead of having 2 separate arrays, you could use an object such as `var cars = { car1: {brand: "BMW", year: 1999}, car2: {brand: "Volvo", year: 2000}, car3: {brand: "Saab", year: 2001} };` :)

Comment: @TylerRoper I aim to get  `BMW car1, Volvo car2, SAAB car3` :). I must a use loop to iterate through the values, no?

Comment: In such a case you wouldn't need the inner loop, nor any references to `[j]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per your comment:

> I aim to get `BMW car1, Volvo car2, SAAB car3`

The loop and creation of the new list can be done using `.map()`. We loop through list of brands, and grab the same index item from `car`. We then combine the two values into a single string: `(brand) (car)`. The result is a new array with a list of brands and cars.

```js
var input = "BMW Volvo Saab";
var brand = input.split(" ");

var input2 = "car1 car2 car3";
var car = input2.split(" ");

var brandCars = brand.map((item,index) => `${item} ${car[index]}`);
console.log(brandCars);
```

Answer (score 1):

cars is iterated with j, so change

```
carOut += car[i] + "<br>"
```

to:

```
carOut += car[j] + "<br>"
```

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comment where the OP adds "I aim to get `BMW car1, Volvo car2, SAAB car3`"

You can solve this by mapping one of the arrays and adding the value of the second array with the iterator of the map.

Hope this helps :>

```js
var input = "BMW Volvo Saab";
var brand = input.split(" ");



var input2 = "car1 car2 car3";
var car = input2.split(" ");



var arr = brand.map((brand, i) => brand + ' ' + car[i]).join(',')

console.log(arr);
```